# How do I use Tortoise SVN through local socks proxy and remote ssh server

Tags: svn, ssh, proxy, tortoisesvn, socks

I'm using TortoiseSVN in Windows 8.1 x64. I'm trying to checkout a SVN server through a local proxy I've configured with putty that tunnels my requests to a remote ssh server but I'm receiving this error:

```
Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

I've  configured TortoiseSVN proxy settings in the standard way but I think it is not the right one.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: see answer to same question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/73475/how-can-i-set-proxy-for-subversion-with-ssh-tunnel